# Accept an answer where the actual answer is located in the comments?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, etiquette, answers-as-comments

I got a rather unsatisfactory answer on Stack Overflow but the subsequent discussion with the answerer (in the comments below) was helpful. Should I accept his answer? Or is there a way to accept a specific comment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The usual way is to ask the answerer to edit their comment into the answer, and then to accept that.

Comment: Unless stackoverflow, in its infinite wisdom, automatically converts your answer back into a comment