# How do I mark a correct answer if the answerer posted a comment instead of an answer?

Tags: discussion, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accept an answer where the actual answer is located in the comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64900/accept-an-answer-where-the-actual-answer-is-located-in-the-comments)

I'd like to give credit to the person who answered my question, but they answered in the comment area of my original post and there is no checkmark next to a comment.  How can I give credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell them to post it as an answer, if they do no seem to be willing to do so you can simply make an answer yourself and reference their comment as the source.